# Remove "RootManageSharedAccessKey" SAS Key from Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

With Azure Service Bus, there are two ways to gain access to the underlying topics/queues. The *main* way is through Shared access policies, although access can also be granted through the Access control (IAM) pane.

I'm designing a solution which will use an Azure Function with a Managed Service Identity (MSI), which will be granted access to the Service Bus Namespace through IAM (granting the function MSI contributor access).

My issue is that the RootManageSharedAccessKey key in the namespace Shared Access policies remains there. I've tried to delete this key through the Azure portal, and PowerShell, but haven't found a way to remove it, or reduce its permissions.

**My question is**: Is there a way to remove/disable the RootManageSharedAccessKey?

Answers to questions before they get asked:

- Corporate security policies don't allow a random root key which never expires to sit around and have access to something which could store confidential information
- I know I could regenerate the SAS key every X minutes via a function, but this is a bit dirty and hacky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local Authentication (SAS) can now be disabled in Service Bus by using a later API version and setting the disableLocalAuth property to false. The [Disable Local Auth](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Policy/PolicyDetailBlade/definitionId/%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Authorization%2FpolicyDefinitions%2Fcfb11c26-f069-4c14-8e36-56c394dae5af) policy can be used to set this requirement via policy.

*Edit:* See also this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/disable-local-authentication [image]

Comment: Thanks milope! Updating the answer to this

Answer (score 2):

You cannot delete that rule and SAS access to Service Bus cannot be turned off.

Comment: Wow... this is a shockingly bad security story.

Comment: SAS authentication can be disabled in Service Bus now.